# AMPScript DatePart(D1, S1): how to retrieve month name?

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

The definition for the AMPScript [DatePart(D1, S1)](https://help.exacttarget.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/content/ampscript/ampscript_syntax_guide/datetime_ampscript_functions/#DatePart) function is missing the argument for month name. It reads as follows:

> "S1    The part of the date to retrieve. Valid values include year
>   (Y), month (M), monthname, day (D), hour (H), and minute "

Does anyone Know how to retrieve month name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want the month name, you can use the [Format()](https://help.exacttarget.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/content/ampscript/ampscript_syntax_guide/utilities_ampscript_functions/#Format) function

```
%%[

var @date1 
set @date1 = Format(Now(), "MMMM")

]%%    
%%=v(@date1)=%%
```

**Output**

```
January
```

Reference: [AMPScript Date and Time Formatting](http://help.exacttarget.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/content/ampscript/ampscript_syntax_guide/#DateTimeFormatting)

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the [FormatDate()](http://wiki.memberlandingpages.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/content/ampscript/ampscript_syntax_guide/utilities_ampscript_functions/#FormatDate) function.  This functions accepts a few additional parameters and is particularly useful when you need to return the month in a different language.

```
%%=FormatDate(Now(), "MMMM",,"es-ES")=%%    /* -- January -- */
```

**Output**

```
enero
```

**tips:**  The 3rd parameter is for formatting the time.  If no time formatting is needed, pass an null value for this parameter.  Also, insure the culture code in the 4th parameter is valid.  If an invalid string is passed, it could cause a run-time error.

Comment: Thank you. This response was helpful also.
I have a follow-up for you: Is there a list defining all of the culture codes (4th parameter) available?

Comment: I haven't found a documented list on SFMC's help site.  But, I was able to find a list by googling. "c# culture codes".  I would recommend testing each one you plan to use first.  All of them may not be supported.  reference: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee825488(v=cs.20).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Here are the accepted values for the second parameter of the [**DatePart()**](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/ampscript/ampscript_syntax_guide/datetime_ampscript_functions/datepart/) function (case insensitive): 
`y`, `m`, `d`, `h`, `mi`, `year`, `month`, `monthname`, `day`, `hour`, `minute`